# Change background color R posterdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, background-color

How can I change the default dark green in `posterdown::posterdown_html` to another color? i tried placing `title_bgcol: "red"` in the YAML, which did not do anything. On the other hand `title_textcol: "red"` does work, but the text color was oke as it was. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with CSS inside the Rmarkdown file, I had to use 2 divs to be able to cover the entire page. You could also use a separate .css file if you'd like, just have to include that in your YAML

````
---
title: "hello"
output: 
  posterdown::posterdown_html
---


```{css, echo=FALSE}
div.title_container{
   background-color: red;
}

div.logo_left{
  background-color: red;
}

```
````

[image]